# Can't get if statement to run correctly

Tags: bash, shell, test

I want to check if a file exists, and if it doesn't exists, I want to ask the user if they'd like to create it. Whether the user inputs Y or N, only "Whatever you say" appears on the screen.

```
#!/bin/bash

#This is testing if a file (myFile) exists

if [ -f ~/myFile  ]
then 
        echo "The file exists!"
else
        echo "The file does not exist. Would you like to create it? (Y/N)"
        read ANSWER
fi

if [ "$ANSWER"="N" ]
then
        echo "Whatever you say!"
else
        touch myFile
        echo "The file has been created!"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for all your speedy replies! Got the script running correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should use whitespace when using the `=` comparison operator. `[ ]` is a shell builtin function. Hence, you have to pass every argument with spaces. So you should do it this way:

```
if [ "$ANSWER" = "N" ]
```

Source: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Answer (score 0):

You need spaces around `=` operator.

```
if [ "$ANSWER" = "N" ]
```

When I need text matching I prefer using `case` over `test` or `[ ... ]`, because it's more flexible and efficient.

```
FILE=~/myFile
if [ -f "$FILE"  ]
then 
        echo "The file exists!"
else
        echo -n "The file does not exist. Would you like to create it? (Y/N) "
        read ANSWER
        shopt -s nocasematch
        case "$ANSWER" in
        n|no)
                echo "Whatever you say!"
                ;;
        *)
                touch "$FILE"
                echo "The file has been created!"
                ;;
        esac
        shopt -u nocasematch
fi
```